# Node.js form values are always returning 'undefined'

Tags: node.js, forms, validation, express

I have seen similar questions, unfortunately I don't have enough rep points to leave a small comment so I have to make a new question.

In my registration form, I am submitting my FirstName and LastName values which are always coming back undefined, which is strange because even if I submit the form with everything empty, these two are the only fields that return undefined. Here is my routes folder

```
/routes/main.js

router.post('/register', function(req, res){
  var firstName = req.body.FirstName;
  var lastName = req.body.LastName;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var cpassword = req.body.cpassword;

//Validation
req.checkBody('firstName', 'First name is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('lastName', 'Last name is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('email', 'E-mail is invalid!').isEmail();
req.checkBody('username', 'Username is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('password', 'Password is required!').notEmpty();
req.checkBody('cpassword', 'Passwords do not match!').equals(password);


var errors = req.validationErrors();

if(errors){
    res.render('register', {
        errors: errors
    });
    console.log('there are form errors');
    console.log(errors);
    console.log(firstName);
    console.log(lastName);
} else {
    console.log('no errors');
}
```

and the markup

```
<h2>Student Registration</h2>
<form method="post" action="/register">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="FirstName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="LastName">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" name="username">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">E-mail</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="email" name="email">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Password</label>
    <input type="Password" class="form-control" name="password">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Confirm Password</label>
    <input type="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" name="cpassword">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="">Register</button>
</form>
```

What really bewilders me is that I am seeing the first and last name values when I console.log them, but they still have a value of undefined. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You havea  typo in your validation. In your form you are submitting `FirstName` and `LastName`, but during validation you are checking for `firsName` and `lastName`

Comment: but how does that matter if I am assigning FirstName to firstName and checking firstName?

Comment: Where are you assigning req.body.firstName? From what I see you are assigning firstName to a new variable: `var firstName = req.body.FirstName;`. Then you validate the body, your validation does not occur on the new variable but rather on the body.

Comment: your suggestion worked...I was just curious as to why it was coming up wrong if I was checking the variable

Comment: ah I see. So rather its checking the actual http body and not the referenced variable, right?

Comment: Thank you!! I upvoted but apparently I'm too much of a newb for it to make a difference :)